# How do I setup JetBrains YouTrack to work on a Windows 8 LAN with IIS Server

Tags: server, jetbrains-ide, youtrack

To setup YouTrack on a Windows LAN with my PC being the server, are these instructions on using a reverse proxy the only way to go about this (using IIS)?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Reverse-Proxy-Configuration.html

Comment: Or could this be achieved by running YouTrack from their Docker image? (in Windows that is)

Answer (score 0):

YouTrack standalone comes along with the built-in web server, so in case if it should be accessible only on LAN there is no need in any additional configuration just a straightforward [installation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Install-YouTrack-MSI-Installation.html) of the product. To get the best performance along with all of the benefits of HTTP2 you may consider configuring reverse proxy using IIS, Nginx or Apache as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Reverse-Proxy-Configuration.html#).